# How can I style a django form with css?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, styles

I tried looking for the answer earlier but couldn't seem to figure out a few things. I'm creating my form in a form.py file so its a python file.

Here is my forms.py file :

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'})
    details = forms.TextInput()
    littype = forms.TextInput()
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = info
        fields = ["name", "details", "littype", "image"]
```

Here is my views.py function for it if it helps find the solution :

```
def uploadform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        redirect(home)
    return render(request, 'uploadform.html', {'form': UploadForm})
```

To style it I thought I could do something like this which I found in another question :

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}))
```

Except I have no idea how to link a css page to that python file. This is what I tried writing but i think it doesnt work because its meant for html but its in a python file :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="templates/form.css">
```

And so I'm just not sure how to style my form. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: You don't need to link css to the python file, CSS should be linked to the parent file, and the  ```myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}))```
Will produce a field with class 'myfieldclass' which will take the styling from the parent file

Comment: Im sort of new to some of these terms as I havent been coding for too long so It would be very helpful if you explained what yoou mean by parent file as from what i know only a folder can contain other files which a file cant do.

Comment: Anybody asking about styling Django forms, ought to consider the  Django-crispy-forms package. Yes I know, somer places may be unwilling to create a dependency on a package from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your template you have to just import the `css` file in the `head tag`, but do ensure you `load static` first.

*html file:*

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          # import the css file here
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'path to css file' %}">
     </head>
     ...
</html>
```

*Within the css file:*

```
# Styling the class 
.myfieldclass{
     width: 30% !important;
     height: 100px !important;
     ...
}
```

But please note that you don't have to import a css file since you can add the style tag in the head tag as well. For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <style type="text/css">
               .myfieldclass{
                    width: 30% !important;
                    height: 100px !important;
                    ...
               }
          </style>
     </head>
     ...
</html>
```

You could apply `css` from the `python` file itself as well.

Approach from the `python` file.

```
# Custom way to set css styling on a form field in python code
def field_style():
     styles_string = ' '

     # List of what you want to add to style the field
     styles_list = [
          'width: 30% !important;',
          'height: 100px !important;',
     ]

     # Converting the list to a string 
     styles_string = styles_string.join(styles_list)
     # or
     # styles_string = ' '.join(styles_list)
return styles_string

class MyForm(forms.Form):
     myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass', 'style': field_style()}))
     # 'style': field_style() .... field_style() will return in this case 'width: 30% !important; height: 100px !important;'
```

Any of those should work but I do recommend doing the styling from the `hmtl` or `css` file instead.

Answer (score 1):

My standard template uses Django block structure so I can group page-specific CSS with its page.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    my html ...
{% endblock %}

{% block extracss %}
{{block.super}}
<style>
    ... page-specific CSS
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Base.html contains an empty block definition

```
{% block extracss %}{% endblock %}
```

which serves to locate the block with other site-wide CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the  `block.super` hint

Answer (score 0):

```
class StocksForm(forms.Form):
    stocks = forms.CharField(
        label="",
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "special",
                "size": "40",
                "label": "comment",
                "placeholder": "Comma Seperated eg - Reliance, Steel, Acrysil.. ",
            }
        ),
    )
```

Template side

```
{% load static %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/cards.css' %}">
```

the stylesheet has got CSS
as

```
.special{
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

This is how django will render the form with the class, and the styling class will be taken from stylesheet

[image]

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just include the CSS in the template header like any other stylesheet

Thanks