# how to insert data to database without forms.py in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This method works fine for me can some one say how to add file or images  like this

```
def insert_students(request);
    name = request.POST['name']
    class = request.POST['class']
    student = studentsmodels(name=name, class=class)
    student.save()
    return redirect('/')
return render(request, "insertpage.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Django forms would make your life so much easier, frankly. However, you can still create objects without forms and add files to them. Instead of `request.POST` the files are stored in `request.FILES` the documentation goes into detail about how files are uploaded:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: while using dajngo form i cant style css. any suggestion?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSp You can use this as a guide to style Django forms https://stackoverflow.com/a/72634093/15978450. Not the only methods of styling Django forms but those should work.

Comment: actually you can, you just have to "disassemble" the form field by field and calling css attributes over it, via widgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
def submit_form(request):
    if request.method == POST:
       name = request.POST["name"]
       class = request.POST["class"]
       if Mymodel.objects.filter(name=name, class=class).exist():
          messages.infor("class and name already exist")
       else:
           MyModel.objects.create(name=name, class=class)
    return render(request, "submit_form.html)
```

**submit_form.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'submit_form' %}" method="post">
  {%csrf_token%}
<input name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text">
<input name="class" type="text" placeholder="Enter Class">
<button class="button is-success is-fullwidth is-medium mt-5"
            type="submit">submit
    </button>
</form>
```